# Link tracking when email content is sent in the SOAP API request?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

We have an email that renders the HTML content passed through a SOAP API request.

```
%%=TREATASCONTENT(HTMLContent)=%%
```

Can link wrapping be added to the links within the HTMLContent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with `httpgetwrap|`.  It's not documented very well and it has some limitations that are outlined in these posts:

[How to track URLs included in HTTPGet()](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70725/how-to-track-urls-included-in-httpget)

[Dynamic Trackable Links in ExactTarget Email](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32329/dynamic-trackable-links-in-exacttarget-email)

Comment: I did try:

    %%[ SET @content = REPLACE(HtmlContent,'href="http','href="httpgetwrap|http') ]%%
    %%=TREATASCONTENT(@content)=%%

But links did not get wrapped.

Comment: So SFMC Support enabled it?  How are you verifying it?   If you do a Guided Send or UI Send, it should wrap them.

Comment: They have to enable 'httpgetwrap'? I am verifying by sending a test email. The links are just the direct link not a wrapped link.

Comment: Yes, it has to be enabled by support (as mentioned in the @JonSakas post)

Comment: Oops...I guess I should read the whole content not just look at the code. :-( Thanks @adamspriggs!!!