# Can a data extension hold special characters and embeded email html?

Tags: ampscript, lookup, html, dataextensions, csv

Im working a complex dynamic build and was thinking of using an ampscript look up array to pull the content from a data extension. The idea being that the content can be updated and uploaded via csv rather then wading through numerous content item and the similar if statements.

How does ET and the CSV work together for embedded html (Special characters)? What should I look out for?

Cheers
jjp

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly store HTML and special characters in Data Extensions.

I would not recommend using a .CSV for getting the data into SFMC.  Tab or pipe-delimited is a better option.  Saving Excel files as Unicode (tab-delimited, .txt) works well.

Link wrapping is a drawback of storing HTML blocks in Data Extensions.  You'll have to hardcode or inject the `httpgetwrap|` prefix for all of your links if you want to track the clicks. It is limited to 100 unique URLs tracked per send job.  That's been discussed several times around here:

[How do I track urls found in a content data extension column that contains other data?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/71839/how-do-i-track-urls-found-in-a-content-data-extension-column-that-contains-other/72392#72392)

[Dynamic trackable links in ExactTarget email](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32329/dynamic-trackable-links-in-exacttarget-email/33959#33959)